# How to destructring nested object in js

Tags: javascript, nested, destructuring

```
let options = {
  size: {
    width: 100,
    height: 200
  },
  items: ["Cake", "Donut"],
  extra: true
};
// destructuring assignment split in multiple lines for clarity
let {
  size: { // put size here
    width,
    height
  },
  items: [item1, item2], // assign items here
  title = "Menu" // not present in the object (default value is used)
} = options;
console.log(title);  // Menu
```

This is working fine, but when I want to get list of data from API it doesn't work with nested destructuring. However, I can show data by using && for example `options && options.title`  it's worked fine.

Comment: *"but when I want to get list of data from API it doesn't work with nested destructuring"* Then the structure of the data might be different than you think. Destructuring always works the same way. Without knowing the structure of the data you want to destructure we cannot really help. Note that for destructuring to work the data needs to exist. If some of the data is optional you have to take that into account.

Comment: Maybe the data is still loading when you try to display it, that's why option && option.title worked.

Comment: @FelixKling without using && data is undefined.

Comment: @menett_a  nested object is still loading , that's can not data show ui , I can fix it normal sense in js , but i can not use destructuring

Comment: show us the real code sample? how it looks like initially, how you are setting data after api call is done?

Comment: how do you fetch the data ? do you use await in an async function to wait for api response to be fulfilled ? seems like you are trying to reach a data that doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

In order to destructure, you have to know the structure of the data that comes in. Maybe you can present your problem in a clear way by showing the structure of your api endpoint result

Comment: copy pasting someone else answer from same post is highly unethical bro... @Raafy

Comment: I'm sorry if it looks that way, but I didn't copy-paste someone else's answer. When I opened this post no one had commented yet.

Comment: No problem, it happens